Issue with mapboxgl not removing layers/source on map
I'm having trouble dynamically remove and re-adding layers to a mapboxgl map.
Here's some pseudocode, unfortunately I'm not able to produce a fully reproducible example since I'm running this code in an R framework using the d3.js library r2d3.
I'm creating a map along with a dropdown that is used to change what's displayed on the map based on user selection in the dropdown:
  //create mapbox map
  mapboxgl.accessToken = token;
  var map2 = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: "map_choropleth_state",
    style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9",
  });

//set default property for map so it knows which field to use for the map fill color  
var dropdown_val = '2014-2022'

//function that initially draws the map   
function loadMap(dropdown_val) {
  map2.on('load', function () {

    // Add source and layers, etc...
    map2.on('load', function () {
      console.log('map on load function!')
      map2.addSource('bb', { type: 'geojson', data: data, generateId: true});
      map2.addLayer({
       'id': 'berlin',
       'type': 'fill',
       'source': 'bb',
       'paint': {
         'fill-color': [
           'step',
           ['get', 'ODpc'+dropdown_val],  // input: number,
           '#feebe2',
            break1, '#fbb4b9',
            break2, '#f768a1',
            break3, '#c51b8a',
            break4, '#7a0177',
            break5, '#7a0177'
           ],
          'fill-opacity': .65
          }
      });

  map2.addLayer({
    'id': 'berlin-stroke',
    'type': 'line',
    'source': 'bb',
    'paint': {
      'line-color': '#000',
      'line-width': [
      'case',
        ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'hover'], false],
        2,
        .5
      ]
    }
  });

    //call the addElement function to create the dropdown menu etc.
    if( !document.getElementById("sidebar") ) {
        // Create and inside the load function instead.
        addElement();
    }
  });
}

loadMap(dropdown_val)

//this will be used to add sidebar to the page
function insertAfter(newNode, existingNode) {
  existingNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, existingNode.nextSibling);
}

function addElement() {

   // create a sidebar to hold dropdown
   const sidebar = document.createElement("div");
   sidebar.className = "sidebar";
   sidebar.id = "sidebar";


  //For the dropdown: Create array of options to be added
  var array = ["2014-2022", "2022","2021","2020","2019", "2018", "2017", "2016", "2015", "2014"];
  var val_array = ["ODpc", "ODpc2022","ODpc2021","ODpc2020","ODpc2019", "ODpc2018", "ODpc2017", "ODpc2016", "ODpc2015", "ODpc2014"];

  //Create and append select list
  var selectList = document.createElement("select");
  selectList.id = "mySelect";
  selectList.className = "mySelect";


  //Create and append the options
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = val_array[i];
    option.text = array[i];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
  }

  //make legend etc.. etc...

  // Connect the event listener
  selectList.addEventListener('change', onChange);

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
  // Get a reference to the parent node
  const parentDiv = document.getElementById("map_choropleth_state").parentNode;

  const mapDiv = document.getElementById("map_choropleth_state");

  //add the sidebar, which will hold the dropdown
  insertAfter(sidebar, mapDiv);

  //add the dropdown
  sidebar.appendChild(selectList);

 };

function onChange(event) {
  const dropdown_val = event.target.value;
  console.log("function onChange dropdown val is: ", dropdown_val); //this works!

  console.log(map2.getStyle().layers) //this prints all the existing layers on map

  // Update the layers depending on the value
  if (map2.getLayer('berlin')) {
    console.log('berlin exists!'); //this works - console prints this statement
    map2.removeLayer('berlin');
  }
  if (map2.getLayer('berlin-stroke')) {
    console.log('berlin-stroke exists!'); //this works - console prints this statement
    map2.removeLayer('berlin-stroke');
  }

  //after layers are removed, remove source.
  if (map2.getSource('bb')) {
     console.log("map source bb exists") //this works - console prints this statement
    map2.removeSource('bb');
  }

}

The dropdown element is working and the dropdown value changes. However, the dropdown should remove (and eventually re-add/update) layers on the onchange.
On the first onchange, it consoles that the berlin layer, the berlin-stroke layer, and the bb source exist. On the second onchange, I can confirm through console.log(map2.getStyle().layers) that the layers berlin and berlin-stroke are removed since these layers are no longer in the array of layers. Furthermore, by the second onchange the console does not print berlin exists!, berlin-stroke exists!, or map source bb exists! so I know these layers/source are being removed.  But the layer is not actually removed from the map itself.
Why is the map not removing these layers, even though I'm removing the layers plus the source?
